# How to localStorage a variable that contains a div and recover it

Tags: javascript, json, object, html, local-storage

This is HTML & Javascript.

I have a variable that contains a div element of the page1. All I need is pass this variable to a page 2 (which gonna be embedded with iframe in page1, inside the div of that variable).

```
//So: (Javascript in page 1)

//This creates the div and gives it an id.
var MainDiv = document.getElementById('div');
MainDiv.id = "It's me!";

//And now, with JSON, "localStorage" it:
localStorage.setItem("MD", JSON.stringify(MainDiv));


//And now, in page2 we retrieve it, but the object is not the same
var Page1Div = localStorage.getItem("MD");
alert(Page1Div .id);
//This will output "undefined";
```

I make a try with jStorage too, (using):

```
$.jStorage.set("MD", MainDiv);
var Page1Div = $.jStorage.get("MD");
```

But still the same output of "undefied".

What I haven't understand, why this isn't capable to store the div object variable in localStorage?.

Comment: How do you expect to stringify a div...?

Comment: Then is not possible to pass a variable that contains a div to another page?

Answer (score 1):

It is not supported by default, but there is another possiblities. You can use this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419749/get-selected-elements-outer-html) for an `outerHTML`. Then you can store this string to `localStorage` and restore it as a dom object by using [jQuery.parseHTML](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsehtml/) after.

Comment: Hmmm.. this appears gonna be impossible. I can't remake the div, because is that div where it is contained (with iframe) the page from where I need modify the attributes of the "father". Hmm, I'm gonna need change my strategy. Well.. thanks anyway, thanks for your time!.